# Throwing internal server error -dropwizard and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dropwizard

Hi i am making demo application using dropwizard and angularjs but facing problem of "500 (internal server error)".

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ttApplication">
<script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/commonController.js"></script>
    <body>

        <div ng-controller="initCtrl">
            <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
            <p>password: <input type="text" ng-model="password"></p>
            <button ng-click="auth(name,password)">button</button>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

commonController.js :

```
var app = angular.module('ttApplication', []);

    app.controller('initCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
       $scope.auth =function(userId,password){
           $http.post('api/service/auth', {
               name: userId,
               password: password
           }).then(function(response) {}, function(err) {
               return err;
           });
       }
    });
```

[Dropwizard] userResource.java :

```
@Path("/service")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserResource.class);
    private UserDao userdao;
    private Validator validator;

    public UserResource(DBI jdbi, Validator validator) {
        this.userdao=jdbi.onDemand(UserDao.class);
        this.validator=validator;

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/auth")
    public Response getUserDetails( User auth ){

        User user = userdao.findByEmail(auth.getEmail());

        if(user.getEmail().length()>0){
            PasswordEncryptor encrypt=new PasswordEncryptor();
            if(auth
                .getPassword()
                .equals(encrypt
                .passwordDecryption(user
                .getPassword()))){

                //logger.info("===================:successsss");
                return Response.ok(user.getName()).build();
            }else{
                return Response
                        .status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .entity("invalid password")
                        .build();
            }
        }
         return Response.ok(user.getName()).build();
    }

    @POST
    public Response postUserDetails(User user) throws URISyntaxException {
        PasswordEncryptor encryptor =new PasswordEncryptor();
        user.setPassword(encryptor.passwordEncryption(user.getPassword()));
        Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations =  validator.validate(user); 
        if(violations.size()>0){
            ArrayList<String> validationMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (ConstraintViolation<User> violation : violations) { 
                    validationMessages
                    .add(violation.getPropertyPath().toString() +": " + violation.getMessage()); 
            }     
            return Response
                    .status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .entity(validationMessages)
                    .build();    
        }else {
            userdao.insert(user);
            return Response
                    .created(new URI(user.toString()))
                    .build();
        }

    }



}
```

server logs:

```
ERROR [2015-06-28 10:38:42,302] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 14a9d56581ccb189
! java.lang.NullPointerException: null
! at resource.UserResource.getUserDetails(UserResource.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
! at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
! at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:164) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:181) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:158) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:305) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.17.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.17.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49) [dropwizard-jetty-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83) [jetty-servlets-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:300) [jetty-servlets-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipFilter.doFilter(BiDiGzipFilter.java:134) [dropwizard-jetty-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29) [dropwizard-servlets-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:44) [dropwizard-jersey-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39) [dropwizard-jersey-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:240) [metrics-jetty9-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.ContextRoutingHandler.handle(ContextRoutingHandler.java:38) [dropwizard-jetty-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [28/Jun/2015:10:38:42 +0000] "POST /api/service/auth HTTP/1.1" 500 110 "http://localhost:9000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36" 17
```

My problem is when i click submit button from html form then it throws "500 internal server error"
but when i check my services through "postman" rest client it  works fine and give me result.

Please help me out !! why it is not working when i submit through HTML.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your angular code. Thought it might be null user values. Tested and works fine without the user dao and validator. Maybe the dao is null. Odd though it works with Postman. Only thing I could think was that some user properties aren't getting sent correctly. But it works fine. Can you tell us which line is causing the NPE.

Comment: When you post from angular, its values are sent correctly?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Marcus Henrique and peeskillet, when i console.log(userId) it contains value xyz@gmail.com, but in userResource auth.getEmail() contains null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post request implementation you are doing a lookup of the user via email 
whereas you are not setting that field in your commonController

```
User user = userdao.findByEmail(auth.getEmail());
```

commoncontroller

```
$scope.auth =function(userId,password){
       $http.post('api/service/auth', {
           name: userId,
           password: password
           email: <email>
       }).then(function(response) {}, function(err) {
           return err;
       });
```

I dont know how you have implemented userdao but I suspect it returns a null User

Comment: Hi abhijeet thanks for responding, but my naming convention is little misplace, i dont need to add extra parameter "email: <email>" because in name: userId i am passing email, so my userId=email, so when i pass through HTML i write name = xyz@gmail.com and password.. ect, its like in this way

Comment: Thanks abhijeet your awesome its a nice catch, when i change name to email its working fine thanks for pointing out this.